# What are some current opinions on WPF?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, terminal-services

I was looking for some current opinions on WPF based on their 4.0 release.

We are trying to decide if we want a Desktop application with a WCF server, or if we want an ASP.Net web app. I would really like to do it in WPF, however some major concerns have come up that I am not sure if WPF can handle. I have looked around online and a lot of WPF reviews are based on the 3.5 version, so I was looking for some current opinions.

1. What sort of Support is out there for it? Microsoft support and Community? Is WPF a dying technology or a growing one?
2. It is harder to find WPF programmers. Is this always going to be the case?
3. What is the performance like for terminal services? The majority of our users login using WYSE thin-clients to a Windows 2003 terminal server. Each server normally has between 10 and 30 people on it on any given day.  Most of our TS users only need basic view/insert/update abilities and our admin staff needs the more advanced features and reporting. The admin users all have XP machines with SP2 or higher.
4. What other concerns should I have about WPF?

Comment: @SLaks: Agreed, its a library. I just keep treating it like a language because its different from what I've done before. Technically speaking, we are going to build the program with C# using the WPF library for the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the underlying concern here is whether or not WPF is a mature enough technology for serious desktop application development.  The answer there is IMHO certainly yes and the proof I offer is Visual Studio 2010.  It is written in WPF, is a major desktop application and has to meet the criteria laid out in your question.

To attempt to head off the 2010 is slow + buggy argument.  Yes, 2010 is not a perfect product and has bugs.  The vast majority of those problems are not purely a WPF issue but instead are related to legacy code, managed native interop or just interesting interactions between old and new technology.

To answer some of the non-technical questions with hand wavy answers ...

- Yes **today** it's *probably* harder to find WPF programmers than say WinForm programmers.  WPF is a newer technology and hence likely won't have as many developers.  Will this be true in the future will only be decided in the future :)
- I feel like there is great support for WPF (see the WPF tag on this site for an example).  When I started doing WPF work for the 2010 release the vast majority of the questions I had were already answered on this site or in blog tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a risk that a technology will become obsolete.  That's just the way it is.  And there's no way to know for sure.

Here is a possible scenario: WPF is being overshadowed by Silverlight, since everyone wants to "do it on the web."  You decide to develop your application in Silverlight (even though it's only a subset of WPF's feature set) and get blindsided by HTML 5, which takes over the world because now you can do everything in the browser without a plugin.  Even Flash becomes obsolete.

Will it happen?  Who knows?

People are still quite happily making Winforms applications, arguably an obsolete technology.  Are they worried about obsolescence?  Probably not.

As far as I know, Microsoft actively and enthusiastically supports this technology.  If you are concerned about performance and other issues, the best way to find out if it meets your needs is to build a prototype.

Answer (score 1):

#1 - I've done projects with WPF. There is quite a bit of information out there. Microsoft seems to be investing more in Silverlight at the moment, but I suspect that WPF and Silverlight will be merged in the coming years. WPF/Silverlight/XAML will be Microsoft's way of building desktop apps for the foreseeable future.

#2 - Developers with good WPF (or Silverlight) skills are hard to find, though not impossible. WPF/Silverlight definitely has a steep learning curve.

#3 - There have been problems with WPF apps running on terminal server because WPF runs on top of DirectX. I would definitely try running a WPF app on your Windows Server 2003 terminal server to see how it behaves. My biggest concern would be that Microsoft would likely be investing in any WPF-related fixes for Server 2008 TS and I'm not sure they would necessarily port those to Server 2003. As for a good test app, I would grab something like the WPF photo viewer demo (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771331%28VS.90%29.aspx). Something reasonably graphically intensive to stress TS.

#4 - Personally #3 is the biggest concern IMHO. If you can't run on Windows Server 2003 TS, the other questions are moot.

Comment: Agreed on #4. I've tested on the TS without any problems, although I haven't tested getting a lot of users into it all doing different things. Nice point about the photoviewer... I might give that a try. Also, there's been talk lately about updating the terminal servers to 2008 and I'm sure we could give it a nudge in that direction to ensure it happens if needed.

Comment: WCF natural habitat is IIS 7 on Server 2008, which gives more incentive to upgrade. Ah, and if the target is .Net 4.0 that also means XP SP3. As for developers - there is an upside too - at least you can be sure that you get people more passionate about technology... or just more lucky ;)

Answer (score 1):

Concern #1: What sort of Support
So far, it's growing and growing well.  The IDE support is finally decent as of VS2010, and it appears as though MS is going to be pushing this for a good amount of time.  There are lost of examples from MS and the community.

Concern #2: It is harder to find WPF programmers.
Well, it depends on how crazy you want to get with your UI.  If you want the latest, greatest whiz bang 3D animations and multiple effects, it might be difficult to find someone off the street with all of those skills that you can afford.  However, if you're banging out a relatively simple UI, many experienced developers can quickly grow into this role.

Concern #3: What is the performance like for terminal services? 
That depends on how much animation and other whiz bang features you want to add.  If there is lots happening on the screen, it will take more bandwidth.  Once again, a simple interface should have no problems.

Concern #4: What other concerns should I have about WPF?
Hard to say!